How to Implement Multi-Company Record Access Control in Odoo 17?
I’m working with an Odoo Community Edition v17 deployment that is configured for a multi-company environment. I want to ensure that users can only see and manage records belonging to their assigned company. However, I’m struggling to correctly configure record rules and ACLs (Access Control Lists).
What I’ve Done:
Defined Multi-Company Setup:
The database is set up with multiple companies, and users are assigned to specific companies.
The res.company and res.users models are properly configured.
Created Record Rules:
I added a record rule for the sale.order model to restrict access to records belonging to the user's current company:
Code
Tested User Access:
Users can see only their company-specific records on some forms but are encountering issues on others (e.g., related fields pulling data from other companies).
For example, users can see products from other companies in the dropdown while creating a sales order.
The Problem:
How can I restrict access at a deeper level to ensure dropdowns, related fields, and reports also follow the same multi-company rules?
Is there a way to debug which record rules are applied in specific contexts?
Are there best practices or Odoo-native solutions to enforce company-based access control uniformly?
What I’m Expecting:
A step-by-step approach to properly configure record rules and ACLs for a multi-company setup.
Tips on handling related fields that bypass record rules.
Recommendations for debugging and testing access control in Odoo effectively.

Did you check the official how-to-guide?

Please copy and paste your code instead of using an image. It makes easier for other users to answer your question.

First of all Odoo standard declare yet a multi-company rules for Sale orders and other principal models:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/17.0/addons/sale/security/ir_rules.xml#L8
And second in your company rules don't use user.company_id.id because it is the default company for Users (different from Enabled Companies in the Context).
